# Possible to access one Azure Virtual Machine through two DNS names using two Cloud Services?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I have purchased a Pay-As-You-Go Azure Subscription with the lowest resources (A0 Basic, shared core and 768 MB RAM) and automatically, four services were created for me: a Storage Account, a Virtual Machine, a Cloud Service and a Directory.

On the Virtual Machine I set up my own HTTP server software written in C# using HttpListener class. I added an HTTP Endpoint connecting the private and public port 80 on TCP. Once I've done that, I was able to access my Cloud Service address (Something.CloudApp.net).

I've created a separate Cloud Service on top of 4 service I already had and now I can't figure out how to make that service use the Virtual Machine so I can access the same HTTP server from both DNS names (Something.CloudApp.net versus SomethingElse.CloudApp.net).

The service status of both services is Created if I investigate in the Microsoft Azure Portal, however, only the first service says Running in Production column in Cloud Service list. The other one doesn't. None of the Cloud Services say anything in the Staging column.

I figure I have to set the other service to run in production too, but when I want to do that, the Portal says "You have nothing deployed to the production environment.", "Upload a new production deployment", which opens a dialog prompting me to provide details for a production environment to be newly created.

Is there a way I can make my other Cloud Service use the production environment of the first service?

Is there an alternative way to make my Virtual Machine accessible through two DNS names offered by Azure (CloudApp.net)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cloud service is the logical container for the VM and a VM can only be in one cloud service.  There is no way to get 2 different *.cloudapp.net URLs to point to the same VM.  What you can do is register 2 custom domain names (www.mydomain1.com, www.mydomain2.com) and use CNAME or A Record to point both of them to the same VM.

Comment: I am very new to Microsoft Azure and I wasn't sure what Cloud Service actually was. Thanks for your answer.